# multiple dojo pie chart

Tags: charts, dojo

How can I add trow pie charts in the same chart? If I add two plots then the pie charts are both in the center. I need to have one on the left side and one on the right side.

I need them in one chart because I want to create an SVG image of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking about that and up to now haven't found the solution.

But we can position the pie-chart by modifying 'g' element of svg with javascript after render.

```
    var a=document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var b=document.getElementsByTagName('g')[1];
    b.setAttribute('transform','translate(-598.25037,-71.249953)'); //put your own
```

Hope this help.